# How to pass on openssl context options from PHP curl

Tags: php, curl, openssl

I am trying to talk to a buggy webserver that I don't control over SSL from PHP+curl.

I wrote a little C-program directly against openssl lib, and through that identified that, if I enable the openssl options SSL_OP_NO_COMPRESSION and SSL_OP_DONT_INSERT_EMPTY_FRAGMENTS explicitly in call to SSL_CTX_set_options(), I can get it to work. Like this:

```
SSL_CTX_set_options(ctx,  SSL_OP_NO_COMPRESSION | SSL_OP_DONT_INSERT_EMPTY_FRAGMENTS)
```

but, ...that is in my isolated C program.

Can I, somehow, make PHP+curl set these options, when it establishes the SSL connection? CURL seems to operate on a much higher level.

Here are my own findings, so far:

- I know about `curl_setopt`, but I see no options like those in its list.
- I have found something called [stream options](http://www.php.net/manual/en/context.ssl.php), but I am not clear on how or if they are used with CURL, and again, I see no match for the options I need.
- The PHP [manual on openssl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.openssl.php) seems to only be about functions to handle keys and certificates.
- Then, there is [HttpRequest setSslOptions](http://php.net/manual/en/httprequest.setssloptions.php), but again, that seems to closely match options to CURL context.

---

**UPDATE**

After the response from "user2076645" on the option on disabling compression, I git cloned the source of PHP and took a look around myself.

Specifically, I found this piece of code:

```
#if OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER >= 0x0090605fL
    ssl_ctx_options &= ~SSL_OP_DONT_INSERT_EMPTY_FRAGMENTS;
#endif
```

which explicitly **disables** the option I need. I looked up the commit message, too, and it was a fix to a possible attack on SSL.

So, I guess it can't be done from PHP, currently :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it helps but there is an option to disable compression

http://git.php.net/?p=php-src.git;a=commitdiff;h=4a01ddfb5569da1b87dd4cac95c3f709fb607396;hp=bb4d11b405ae1f37a8b0e4db630e80c5678f0746

Comment: Whoa, thanks. But, that commit seems to be only about 14 days old. I guess I need to run a bleeding edge PHP version to get that :-)